# How to regex from pattern X to the next occurrence of X, recursively, getting the content between as matches

Tags: c#, regex

With regex, by doing `(?s)X(.*?)Y` on the following strings:

```
X
aaa
Y
X
bbb
Y
X
ccc
Y
```

I get:

```
Match1.Group1: "aaa"  
Match2.Group1: "bbb"  
Match3.Group1: "ccc"
```

I'd like to get the same result (matches and groups) with the following:

```
X
aaaa
X
bbbb
X
cccc
```

But I cannot wrap my head around how to do that. Thank you for taking the time to read and reply.

I've tried everything I can think. I use C# language and https://regex101.com/ to test the regex statement.

Comment: Perhaps [`(?<=X)(?:[^X]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/3DoVYy/1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "X\naaaa\nX\nbbbb\nX\ncccc";

        //modify the regex pattern to exclude "X"
        string pattern = @"(?s)X((?:(?!X).)*)";

        //matching the pattern in the input string
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Match{i + 1}.Group1: \"{matches[i].Groups[1].Value}\"");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match1.Group1: "aaaa"
Match2.Group1: "bbbb"
Match3.Group1: "cccc"
```

Comment: Wow! Super! Just what I was looking for. I very much appreciate you taking the time :)

Comment: You are using the [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) technique, meant for avoiding strings of two or more characters. There's no point in using it to avoid a single character (`"X"`), however, as `[^X]` (or `[^\r\nX]`) would do.

Answer (score 1):

Without Regex:

```
string txt = "X\naaaa\nX\nbbbb\nX\ncccc";
string[] matches = txt.Replace("\n",null).Split(new string[] {"X"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `.*?` that you use can als match a `X` char, so you have to prevent matching an `X` char until the first occurrence of a `Y` char.

As you are already using a capture group, you can capture the value using a negated character class `[^` without using `(?s)`

If you don't want to trim the value, and there should be at least a single non whitespace character other than `X` in between:

```
X\s*([^\sX](?:[^X]*[^\sX])?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9N6Q9k/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/INhkNY)

```
string pattern = @"X\s*([^\sX](?:[^X]*[^\sX])?)";
string input = @"X
aaaa
X
bbbb
X
cccc
XX";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

---

A match only version instead of a capture group with a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=X\s*)[^\sX](?:[^X]*[^\sX])?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JN8qk0/1)

---

Or the more simplified pattern, capturing any character:

```
X([^X]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UwLYz5/1) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/SBPBKb)